String Interpolation in an NSAppleScript Script
My app tries to run an AppleScript:
do shell script "mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk3s1 ~/Unscrewer" user name "lucasdrouot" password "MDP" with administrator privileges 
For this I use NSAppleScript and everything works perfectly.
But when I try to include the mainDiskName variable in my script, although it contains the right value, the script returns an error that the disk is invalid....
I tried to use a static variable but it doesn't work.
Here's my code :
@State var mainDiskName: String = "disk3s1"

func mountSystemVolume() {
        runCommand("mkdir -p ~/Unscrewer")
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let homeDirectory = fileManager.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
        let folderPath = homeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Unscrewer")

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: folderPath.path, isDirectory: nil) {
            let diskName = mainDiskName
                    
            appleScript("""
    do shell script "mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/\(diskName) ~/Unscrewer" user name "lucasdrouot" password "MDP" with administrator privileges
    """)
        } else {
            errorAlert = true
            alertTitle = "No such file or directory"
            
            let errorDetails = """
            More Info: No such file or directory: ~/Unscrewer
            """
            
            alertMessage = errorDetails
        }
    }

